Can the general formula for quartic equation be simplified?
This question arises from an unusual method of solving depressed quartic
$x^4 + ax^2 + bx + c = 0$
which extracts the value of each root from the product of four radical expressions. I will give an example with $a = -880, b = -5760$ and $c = 36864$, without going into details:
Resolvent cubic:
$z^3 - az^2 - 4cz +4ac - b^2 = 0$
$z_1 = 416, z_2 = - 816, z_3 = - 480$
We define that
$\cos \omega_n = \sqrt{1/2 + \sqrt{1/4 - c/z_n^2}}$
$\sin \omega_n = \sqrt{1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - c/z_n^2}}$
for $n =1, 2, 3$.
$\cos \omega_1 = 3/ \sqrt{13}, \, \sin \omega_1 = 2/ \sqrt{13}$
$\cos \omega_2 = 4/ \sqrt{17}, \, \sin \omega_2 = 1/ \sqrt{17}$
$\cos \omega_3 = 2/ \sqrt{5}, \, \sin \omega_3 = 1/ \sqrt{5}$
We let
$R = \sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4c} - a} = \sqrt{1105}$
Solutions:
$x_1 = + 2R \sin \omega_1 \sin \omega_2 \sin \omega_3 = + 4$
$x_2 = + 2R \sin \omega_1 \cos \omega_2 \cos \omega_3 = + 32$
$x_3 = - 2R \cos \omega_1 \sin \omega_2 \cos \omega_3 = - 12$
$x_4 = - 2R \cos \omega_1 \cos \omega_2 \sin \omega_3 = - 24$
Thus, for example, the first root is obtained as a product of the following expressions:
$x_1 = 2\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{4c} - a} \sqrt{1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - c/z_1^2}} \sqrt{1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - c/z_2^2}} \sqrt{1/2 - \sqrt{1/4 - c/z_3^2}}$
To check my hypothesis on this expression, I tried replacing the roots of the cubic $(z_n)$ with expressions that include only the coefficients of the quartic $(a, b, c)$, but it's a complicated, error-prone process, and I gave up.
Despite these encouraging signs, I'm not 100% sure that the general formula for the quartic equation can be further simplified. That's why I'm asking.
Here is the complete solution for each quartic equation:

